# If I load my database connection pool does it affect the main netty thread?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Say I have a action method that connects to the database like this:

```
@Singleton
class Users @Inject()(userService: UserService) extends Controller {
  def dbtest = Action {
    val user = userService.getById(1)
    Ok("the user name is" + user.name)
  }
}
```

I'm using Guice to inject the service into the controller, and the code for that is follows:

```
class UserServiceImpl @Inject(val userDao: UserDao) extends UserService {
  def getById(userId: Int): User = {
    db.withSession { implicit session =>
      return userDao.getUserId(userId)
    }
  }
}
```

I have a abstract class that my UserService extends which looks like:

```
trait BaseService {
  val ds = JDBCWrapper.datasource  // org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
  val db = Database.forDataSource(ds)
}
```

Each service will be sharing the same instance of the datasource `ds`.

So this is creating a connection pool, possible multiple threads, inside of playframework.

Will this be a problem since netty uses a single thread or is that creating at a different level where play and netty interact?

I've read somewhere where sometimes in play people create a fixed sized thread pool and perform certain operations in that context, is that what I am suppose to be doing with my database operations?

**Is this a bad design?**

I am not using that play-slick plugin as I am wiring this up manually b/c I am using a multi-project sbt setup (and I what to understand this issue regardless).

Comment: If you don't have async jdbc/some pother type driver I strongly recommend perform all blocking operations (jdbc is all blocking) in separate thread pool.

Comment: @EugeneZhulenev I see, can you explain the reasoning behind this?  That's what I am trying to understand.

Comment: You can read "Blocking Needs Careful Management" section in Akka docs http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html. Play(Netty) is not built on top of Akka, but idea of careful blocking operations in "main application path" is the same.